# how to create two custom registration forms in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am wondering whether it is possible to have two different registration forms.
I would like hidden field with two different values in these two forms. The hidden field is role and the value can be "buyer" or "seller".

I would like to embed the role in registration form according to the role.

I have made this route where role is passed via url.

```
devise_scope :user do
     get "/users/sign_up/:role" => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => 'new_user_with_role'
 end
```

In registrations/new form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => params[:role]  %>
```

This gives a feeling of two separate registration forms. This works but when there is error in submitting signup form then in the view after error, the hidden field value is cleared. The hidden value is required in order to create the account with role.

Is there a way to preserve the role hidden field when there is error in submitting signup form?

Comment: Having a model buyer and a model seller will not be suitable?

For my part I have an application with a registration form USER and EDITOR. The forms are both different.

However, if you manage to display a hidden field after a failed registration attempt, do not hesitate to share it because it interests me too :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this quite simply by using [Single Table Inheritance](https://medium.com/@dcordz/single-table-inheritance-using-rails-5-02-6738bdd5101a). Instead of your `role` field lets add `type` column to `users`.

```
class AddTypeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
    add_index :users, :type
    remove_column :role, type: :string
  end
end
```

We then create two subclasses of user:

```
# app/models/buyer.rb
class Buyer < User
end

# app/models/seller.rb
class Seller < User
end
```

Don't worry. Both will still be saved in the `users` table. But when you save a `Buyer` instance it sets the `type` column to `Buyer`. The reason you want to do this is that it lets you reuse the Devise mappings implementation.

We then setup Devise to render scoped views. Edit `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true
```

Then lets setup the routes for each type:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :sellers, only: :registrations
  devise_for :buyers, only: :registrations
end
```

Now setup your custom views. You can generate the Devise views with `rails g devise:views -v registrations`.

```
# app/views/buyers/registrations/new.html.erb
<h2>Sign up as a Buyer</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%- # you have to override the resource name or Devise will try to use new_buyer_session_path -%>
<%= render "devise/shared/links", resource_name: 'user' %>
```

Comment: Edited. You don't need to override the controller. I just forgot to set `config.scoped_views = true`.

Comment: Hello, with your solution I am having a problem when I add fields (name or fullname) in buyer / registrations / new.html. I create a db buyer, a model and a buyer / registratons_controller but nothing solves the problem. Name and fullname = nil :(

Comment: Thats a completely separate question @Clyde T.